# Trying to change the value of a card

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm making a blackjack game for school and right now we are working on the Hand class (adds a card, and checks if the user bust/won/etc)

I'm working on the addCard method

```
/**
 * Adds a card from the deck to the hand
 */
public void addCard(Card c)
{
    hand.add(c);
    if(getHandValue() > 21)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < hand.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if(hand.get(i).equals("Ace") == true && getHandValue() > 21)
            {
                c.changeAce();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I tried adding and Ace, Two, Ace to my hand, it isn't changing the value from 11 to 1 like it should, it's still adding it up as 11 2 11 and then telling me the hand busted.

Can anyone find the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Post [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can just simply do `if(hand.get(i).equals("Ace") && getHandValue() > 21)`

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't it need the for loop so it can go through the whole arraylist and check the cards?

Comment: @Ian - can you edit your question and provide the implementation for the getHandleValue and the Card.changeAce functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating while `i < hand.size()-1` this means it will skip the last element so the last ace doesn't get changed.

Try `i < hand.size()`

Comment: I just tried that and it is still not changing the ace.

Comment: Whoops, needed to add an equal sign, just fixed it. Thanks for the help